# HandsonTable Conditional Formatting

Tags: javascript, formatting, conditional-statements, handsontable

How can I change the  background if any of the  cell value is empty? This function only change the TD background, not the whole row.

```
function invalidRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';    
    td.style.background = '#A9A9A9';
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with handsontable, but is the parameter `row` a reference to the `<tr>`? In that case you could probably set its style. If not, try using `td.parentNode` to access the table row in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the entire parent row, you could do:

```
$(td).parent().style.background = '#A9A9A9';
```

This will apply the style to the parent of the `td` which is the `tr` which is the row.